# IOS Example of initWithCGColor

Tags: ios, uikit, uicolor

I give in, this is taking **too long** and I can't find the answer listed anywhere.

In the **Framework Reference** for **UIColor** there is a function initWithCGColor. How do you use this? Can someone please help with example? I am looking to initialize a color to a specific value!

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIColor_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIColor/initWithCGColor:

Comment: what do you mean by **to a specific value**?

Comment: A specific value of what? Do you already have a `CGColorRef`? Can you give more detail of what you're actually trying to do rather than how you think you ought to be doing it?

Comment: initWithCGColor: used to convert color from Core Graphics CGColorRef to UIColor. Sorry, but from your question is totally unclear what information you are asking for and what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Hi guys. My apologies for the mediocrity of my question. It is my estimation though that others periodically stumble into the same thought process so I posted it up here for them in the future.

Comment: Clarification Statement: How can I do UIColor.customColor(r,g,b)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CGColorRef is a class used for drawing using Core graphics. If you want to initialise an `UIColor`object with a specific RGB value, use 
`- initWithRed:green:blue:alpha:`

**Swift**

```
let color = UIColor(red: 59/255.0, green: 136/255.0, blue: 195/255.0, alpha: 1)
```

**Objective-C**

```
 UIColor * color = [UIColor colorWithRed:59/255.0f green:136/255.0f blue:195/255.0f alpha:1];
```

---

For helping purposes, I add some useful extension/macro for UIColor in order to initialise objects without having to consider the division by 255.
I am not the creator of this code but a grateful user who wants to share some time-saving code :

**Swift**

```
public extension UIColor{

    class func initRGBA(r r:CGFloat, g:CGFloat, b:CGFloat, a:CGFloat) -> UIColor
    {
        return UIColor(red:r/255, green: g/255, blue: b/255, alpha: a)
    }

    class func initRGB(r r:CGFloat, g:CGFloat, b:CGFloat) -> UIColor
    {
        return UIColor.initRGBA(r:r, g:g, b:b, a:1)
    }

    class func initRGBGRAY(gray:CGFloat) -> UIColor
    {
        return UIColor.initRGBA(r:gray, g:gray, b:gray, a:1)
    }
    convenience init(rgb: UInt) {
        self.init(
            red: CGFloat((rgb & 0xFF0000) >> 16) / 255.0,
            green: CGFloat((rgb & 0x00FF00) >> 8) / 255.0,
            blue: CGFloat(rgb & 0x0000FF) / 255.0,
            alpha: CGFloat(1.0)
        )
    }  
}

/// Let's initialize a color
let color = UIColor.initRGB(r: 24, g: 80, b: 145)
```

**Objective-C**

```
#define RGBCOLOR(r,g,b) [UIColor colorWithRed:(r)/255.0f green:(g)/255.0f blue:(b)/255.0f alpha:1]
#define RGBACOLOR(r,g,b,a) [UIColor colorWithRed:(r)/255.0f green:(g)/255.0f blue:(b)/255.0f alpha:(a)]
#define RGBGRAYCOLOR(g) [UIColor colorWithRed:(g)/255.0f green:(g)/255.0f blue:(g)/255.0f alpha:1]

/// Let's initialize a color
UIColor * color = RGBCOLOR(87, 99, 132);
```

Comment: You're welcome. Are you using Swift or ObjC ? I have some macros useful for initializing UIColors objects.

Comment: I hope you realize how much time such an answer helps sooo many people. The cumulative hours you've saved us all here, thank you